# Why is the reverse animate() not firing right away?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using $(window).scroll to animate the top header of my site when scrolling away from the very top of the viewport. The initial condition works fine, with all my animate() effects working. The problem is that when I scroll back to the top of the page, the header doesn't animate back to the original settings (a few times it has, but after a long pause).

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ocbkkyk/

jQuery:

```
var $headerBar   = $(".header"),
    $window    = $(window),
    offset     = $headerBar.offset(),
    topPadding = 0;

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
        //$headerBar.stop().animate({
            //marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
        //});

        console.log('Left the Top');

        // Add class 'fixed'
        $headerBar.addClass('moved');

        $('p.mainprinav_text').animate({ padding: '20px 45px 20px 0' });
        $('ul.mainprinavlist li a').animate({ padding: '20px 35px' });
        $('div.headerlogo').animate({ top: '6px' });
        $('div.headerlogo img').animate({ width: '90px' });
        $('body.site').animate({ paddingTop: '38px' });

    } else if ($window.scrollTop() <= offset.top) {
        //$headerBar.stop().animate({
            //marginTop: 0
        //});

        console.log('Back to Top');

        // Remove class 'fixed'
        $headerBar.removeClass('fixed');

        $('p.mainprinav_text').animate({ padding: '39px 45px 39px 0' });
        $('ul.mainprinavlist li a').animate({ padding: '39px 35px' });
        $('div.headerlogo').animate({ top: '13px' });
        $('div.headerlogo img').animate({ width: '120px' });
        $('body.site').animate({ paddingTop: '0' });
    }
});
```

Comment: That is a **lot** of code. Most of it is completely unrelated to the question. Please edit it, so that only the minimum amount required to reproduce the problem remains.

Comment: You are calling `.animate()` *MANY* times, which is the cause of the delay. You need to only call it once when reaching top, and once again when leaving the top. Not every time the scroll happens.

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle that shows the effect. Thanks for Kevin. Could you please tell me how I consolidate all animate() into one for different selectors that have different adjustments for the effect? Perhaps my code needs to be restructured? Is there a problem with my approach to this?

Comment: Sorry, didn't paste the correct url to the jsfiddle. It's there now.

Comment: You can have multiple animates happening, but you only want each of them to happen once per scroll period, rather than once per scroll event. For example, when you scroll from the top of the page to the bottom of the page, the scroll event will trigger several thousand times, depending on the height of the page and the speed of the scroll. That means your animate methods will also be called several thousand times. you need to debounce this such that it only triggers once rather than several thousand times.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Kevin. What would I use instead of $(window).scroll to fire the animations?

Comment: you still want to use scroll, but you'll want a flag that you can set so that each condition will only happen once. for example, if condition and flag, do this, else if other condition and !flag, do this and toggle the value of the flag inside of each condition.

Comment: Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0Lccg9yx/2/ i removed the .stop() calls to demonstrate that it does solve the problem, however you'll also want to add the stop calls back in as to prevent buildup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem**

is that there is nothing to prevent buildup.

if you add `.stop()` before each `animate(...)` then it will prevent the queue buildup you're experiencing that causes the delay in animations.

**Like [in this fiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/0Lccg9yx/)**

Though there are also other things that can make this better as well. You should have a switch so each part of the script only fires once, the animations can be replaced with css so you could just toggle a class, and the whole thing can be done with much less code.

*If you're interested in these other changes I can make another fiddle to illustrate.*

Comment: If you would be so kind, would you mind showing me how to do this with the other suggestion you had? Thank you FiLeVeR10

Comment: @ScriptsConnect does the fiddle solve the delay issue you were experiencing?

Comment: By adding .stop(), yes. It solves the problem wonderfully. Thank you for pointing that out to me.

Comment: @ScriptsConnect I've cleaned it up, simplified the css and jquery (now ~10 lines), and now you can just toggle a class on `body` and the css handles the animations. http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/uoun5mya/ Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Your CSS3 solution is a lot smoother, and makes more sense. I'm just worried about cross-browser support. Overall, really nice. Thank you very much for all of your help.

Comment: @ScriptsConnect it should cover IE10+ and all other modern browsers. In earlier versions like <=IE9 it will still execute the css change with no animation.